# Не получаю ответ на get запрос

Tags: php

Не могу передать `Get` запрос на сервер [Sypex Geo.](http://sypexgeo.net/ru/api/)

Код:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.sypexgeo.net/xml/123.45.67.89");
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$info =  curl_getinfo( $ch );
var_dump($info); 
var_dump($content);
```

`$content` возвращает `false`,
`$info` содержит массив:

```
array(21) { ["url"]=> string(40) "http://api.sypexgeo.net/xml/123.45.67.89" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бывает необходимо добавлять доп. опции для `curl` запроса.
Как вариант попробовать:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4");
```

Если работа происходит на снимаемом хосте, на каком-нибудь бесплатном, то там бывает отключают `allow_url_fopen`. По разным причинам

Если же работа происходит на локальном хосте - нужно убедиться, что в настройках `php.ini` стоит настройка `allow_url_fopen`, позволяющая работать с `curl` и обертками